# Android Nougat PopupWindow showAsDropDown(...) Gravity not working

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-7.0-nougat

I have this code.

```
PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow();
popUp.setFocusable(true);
popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);        
popUp.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
popUp.setHeight(600);

popUp.setContentView(anchorView);
popUp.showAsDropDown(anchorView);
popUp.update();
```

And its perfectly works on Android Version < Android Nougat. But in Android Nougat, the popup is being displayed at the top of the screen instead of relative to the anchor view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems a bug in android 7.0. But you can solve it with a 
compatible way.

```
PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow();
popUp.setFocusable(true);
popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);        
popUp.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
popUp.setHeight(600);

popUp.setContentView(anchorView);
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=24) {
     int[] a = new int[2]; //getLocationInWindow required array of size 2
     anchorView.getLocationInWindow(a);
     popUp.showAtLocation(((Activity) mContext).getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0 , a[1]+anchorView.getHeight());
    } else{
     popUp.showAsDropDown(anchorView);
}

popUp.update();
```

Google will fix this bug in the future build. And there is a final workaround. You need give the height when creating pop.

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(contentView, with, height);
```

Init pop as above, and you can only use 
  popUp.showAsDropDown(anchorView)  show this popup. In this way, you can ignore the version of the Android API.

Comment: It works only in api 24 not in 25. Pls provide if anybody knows answer to this issue.

Comment: I asked a question specifically for API 25: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973893/android-nougat-7-1-1-howatlocation-gravity-not-working

Answer (score 6):

7.0 and 7.1 to achieve different, so to be dealt with separately.

The following method I tested in the virtual machine(7.0 and 7.1), no problem.

```
public void showFilterWindow(Context context, PopupWindow popupWindow,View showView, int xoff, int yoff) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
            //7.0 The following system is used normally
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(showView, xoff, yoff);
        } else {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            showView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            int offsetY = location[1] + showView.getHeight() + yoff;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 25) {
                //【note!】Gets the screen height without the virtual key
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                int screenHeight = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
                /*
                 * PopupWindow height for match_parent,
                 * will occupy the entire screen, it needs to do special treatment in Android 7.1
                */
                popupWindow.setHeight(screenHeight - offsetY);
            }
            //Use showAtLocation to display pop-up windows
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(showView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, offsetY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The bug still exists on Oreo, at least on the emulators. I would recommend changing the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT check to be >=25

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this problem appears only in Android 7.0 (API 24). In 7.1.1 (API 25) everything is OK on same devices. After some research defined that the problem caused by `popUp.update()`, like it is already mentioned by [Marilia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315633/7339798). But if you just remove `popUp.update()`, the popup won't appear in versions prior to API 24. In order to avoid this the only way now is to use version check and don't use `update()` method only on devices with API 24. Here is the solution, which worked for me:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 24) {
   popup.update(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

Tested it on different devices and APIs and it works well everywhere from API 18 and up to API 25.

Comment: Please post complete code. I'm having problems with API 25 when I created a similar fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973893/android-nougat-7-1-1-howatlocation-gravity-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that `popUp.update();` in your code? I was having a similar problem, in my case I didn't need the `popUp.update();` and removing it made the popup gravity behave as expected.

Also, this is most likely a related issue, reported about `PopupWindow.showAtLocation()`:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221001

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Please try it

```
    protected void showSortPopup(View anchorView) {


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
        Rect rectf = new Rect();
        anchorView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);
        int offsetY = (rectf.top + anchorView.getHeight());
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) Manager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int screenHeight = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        mPopup.setHeight(screenHeight - offsetY);
    }
    mPopup.showAsDropDown(anchorView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android API 29, I fixed by replacing popup width and height as `WRAP_CONTENT`. As in my code in *Kotlin*.

```
private fun createSpinnerLikePopUp() {
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_window, null, false)
            popUp = PopupWindow(context).apply {
            isFocusable = true
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            contentView = vw
            setBackgroundDrawable(null)
        }
        vw!!.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = RecyclerAdapter(context, myArray)
        }
    }
```

And button click as follows:

```
displayPopupBtn.setOnClickListener { view ->
            if (popUp != null) {
                if (popUp.isShowing) {
                    popUp.dismiss()
                } else {
                    popUp.showAsDropDown(view)
                }
            }
        }
```